# Supporting multiple materials per mesh

Tags: opengl, mesh, vbo

My mesh class has a single VAO index, and an index for one buffer of vertices, colours, tex coords, normals and indices (if used). I'm loading Wavefront .obj files into that mesh class and treating all groups as one VBO, I then load a single material separately and bind it before drawing the mesh. This works fine but I'm now looking to support .obj files with multiple materials.

The easiest way would be to just create a new mesh instance for each group within the .obj that uses a different material and group them into a meshGroup object or something, the better(?) way would be to support multiple VBOs within my mesh's VAO, assigning different materials when drawing each buffer. Is the second way faster than the other (since there would only be VAO binding per mesh rather than per group), or can I cop out and go with the first method?

EDIT: I've got it working by going with method 1 and creating a separate mesh instance (and associated VAO) for each part of the mesh with a different material. I'm sure this isn't the best way, so if anyone has any insight it would be much appreciated!

Comment: The number of *rendering commands* is what matters, not the number of buffer objects. There is no reason to change buffer objects just to render different parts of a mesh

Comment: I didn't realise that glDrawArrays() takes the first element to start drawing from - silly me! So I can keep a single VBO of each type (vertex, normal e.t.c) for the whole mesh, and just render different parts of it, assigning textures in between the glDrawArrays() calls.

Comment: However, how would I do this if I wanted to use an index array? VAOs can only store one, so how would I break up calls to glDrawElements() with different texture bindings?